# SQL inserting last ID from another table

Tags: mysql

I am currently using a web app and am trying to insert records into the Database from user info.
We have 3 tables, Item, User, Item_Status_History

`Item_Status_History` takes in `Item_ID` (the pk from `Item`) and `User_ID` from `user`. I run two queries to insert new records from a user before running the `Item_Status_History` insert, i need to grab the `MAX(Item_ID)` and `MAX(User_ID)` from the previous just inserted records to insert into `Item_Status_History`.

Here is the query i have tried but does not work

```
INSERT INTO Item_Status_History(Item_FK, User_FK, Status_FK, ISH_Date, ISH_Time, ISH_Location) 
SELECT MAX(Item_ID), MAX(User_ID) from Item i, User u 
values (i.Item_ID, u.User_ID, 'Lost', 2022-01-01, 3:00, "Test")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use both `SELECT` and `VALUES` as sources in the same `INSERT` query, it's one or the other.

That said, don't use `MAX()`, as this could change if another process inserts another user or item (although this is mitigated if you put all the queries in a transaction). The function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the ID that was assigned  by the last `INSERT` query in the current session, this is the preferred way to assign foreign keys.

And another syntax issue: The date and time need to be in quotes.

```
INSERT INTO User ...;
SET @user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO Item ...;
SET @item_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO ItemStatus_History (Item_FK, User_FK, Status_FK, ISH_Date, ISH_Time, ISH_Location) 
VALUES values (@item_id, @user_id, 'Lost', '2022-01-01', '3:00', "Test");
```